# List of strings with another list of string inside of it to a single string

Tags: python, string, list

I have this list of strings with another list of strings inside of it and i want to convert it into a single string, how do i do it? (Python)
Example:

```
list =["okok", ["kappa", "ok"], "okok"]
```

I tried to use join but it doesn't work (like this:
listToString = "".join (list)

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Done what you asked, hope it's more clear now. I couldn't add that as code, idk why, i'm on mobile right now, sorry

Comment: Does it add the sublist at the end of the main list?

Comment: @Błotosmętek This isn't the same as the list here is mixed string and list. Only some answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857703/987358) work here.

Comment: Then maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists ?

Comment: @Błotosmętek Yes

Comment: Yepyepyep, thanks a lot dude